# Get the type name of a Dictionary with generics in C#

Tags: c#, types, reflection

Is there an easy or elegant way to get the type name of a Dictionary with the generic types in C#?

Currently I have this code works:

```
if (property.PropertyType.Name == "Dictionary`2")
{
    Type[] arguments = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
    Type keyType = arguments[0];
    Type valueType = arguments[1];
    properties[property.Name] = $"Dictionary<{keyType.Name},{valueType.Name}>";
}
```

I was wondering whether there is more easy way of achieving this formatted string that I'm looking for, like: "**Dictionary<type, type>**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using *recursion*, i.e.

```
private static string MyTypeName(Type type) {
  if (type.IsArray)
    return $"{MyTypeName(type.GetElementType())}[]";

  if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
    return type.Name[0..type.Name.IndexOf('`')];
  if (type.IsGenericType) 
    return $"{MyTypeName(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition())}<{string.Join(", ", type.GenericTypeArguments.Select(t => MyTypeName(t)))}>";

  return type.Name;
}
```

Demo:

```
// Let's have an elaborated type to test the routine
var type = typeof(Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>[]>[][]);

Console.Write(MyTypeName(type));
```

Output:

```
Dictionary<Int32, HashSet<String>[]>[][]
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Z5dIM)

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for